# Вопрос касательно Gulp 4

Tags: gulp, gulp4

Я сейчас изучаю Gulp 4. И у меня возникло два вопроса, на которые надеюсь получить ответ или ссылку на источники:

1. В некоторых статьях видел, что в gulpfile.js функции "экспортируются" или что-то в этом роде. Например `exports.style = style` , где вместо style может быть другое название функции.
   Хотел бы узнать, зачем это и обязательно ли это/рекомендуется ли это.
2. При экспорте на Github-репозиторий `push`-ится только папка со
   всеми оптимизированными файлами + index.html (просто хочу уточнить)?

Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: на youtube есть отличное вдиео и очень подробное про gulp4 - показать ссылку или сами найдёте ?

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо, если бы ссылку предоставили.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2S423N-ETA

Comment: Как оказалось, я уже просматривал это видео. Но там автор не затрагивает тему "экспорта", к сожалению.